# C function type without a typedef

Tags: c, declaration, function-declaration

Suppose we have many C functions with the same signature and return type:

```
R f(X x,Y y){...}
R g(X x,Y y){...}
R h(X x,Y y){...}
```

where `X` and `Y` are the types of the arguments and `R` is the type of the result.

We can declare those functions, for instance in a header file or as forward declarations, like this:

```
R f(X,Y);R g(X,Y);R h(X,Y);
```

or more concisely:

```
R f(X,Y),g(X,Y),h(X,Y);
```

or, avoiding most repetition:

```
typedef R F(X,Y);
F f,g,h;
```

Can that be done in a single statement, without a separate `typedef`?

Comment: Aside from code golf, is there actually a reason to _want_ to avoid this repetition?

Comment: If you do not plan to use it in function pointers declaration do not hide it. Do not save the keyboard.

Comment: What problem does "done in a single statement" solve? Are you code golfing or something?

Comment: @Cubic Yes - I want to know C well and I hate repetitions.

Comment: @Lundin I think it would look better in a single statement. If it's possible to "inline" the function type, this would also have implications in more complex types I use. Here I'm not playing golf. I just hate repetitions.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI What is the correct term for `;`-terminated fragment of C code?

Comment: There is no single term for that. Not all statements end with a `;` either.

Comment: @ngn It does not. `R f(X,Y),g(X,Y),h(X,Y);` is completely unreadable gibberish. For the love of obfuscated C, please do never put "do not repeat yourself" paradigm over "keep it stupid simple". The former has some merits but if taken to the extreme, it leads to dangerous, buggy and unreadable code.

Comment: Bad idea, very, very bad idea.

Comment: Guys, I understand how your dislike of code that looks unfamiliar may have formed, but, for the sake of reducing noise on StackOverflow, please stay on topic. My question wasn't "Is this a good idea?". It was a concrete technical question and I believe I explained it clearly enough to rule out doubts of an X->Y problem.

Comment: "*dislike of code that looks unfamiliar*", @ngn?  Really?  Condescending to the experts from whom you are seeking answers is rarely a wise strategy.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Where did you see condescendance in that..? Also, SO users are not a uniform mass of equally experienced, equally skilled experts. Some users criticized the goal for irrelevant reasons (preconceived notions about coding style and hostility to "code golf") instead of answering how to achieve that goal - my comment was addressed at that lot.

Comment: I see condescendance **all over it**, and it's a shame that you do not recognize that yourself even when it is pointed out to you.  In any case, I assure you that unfamiliarity is not the reason for any of the criticism of your objective, most of which is coming from well-known and respected participants in the C tag.  That doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't ask the question, but you disserve yourself by being dismissive of their criticisms.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "_unfamiliarity is not the reason_" - If any of them (users who criticized style) was familiar with this function declaration style, they would have answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not checked yet but maybe in C23 there is possible to write

```
typeof( R( X, Y ) ) f, g, h;
```

Comment: |If you havent check, why yuo anwer?

Comment: @0___________ I have no a possibility to check that at present but if you or somebody else can check you or he can write for example in a comment that it is invalid. In this case I will just remove my answer.:)

Comment: Although this is really just a typedef by another name. The main difference between typeof and typedef is that typeof is not backwards compatible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)#Keywords

Comment: This seems to have more to do with GNU extensions than the version of the C standard. `gcc10` supports it even with `-std=gnu90`. Strangely, my `clang17` hangs with such code.

Comment: @ngn As it is pointed to in the answer it is now a C23 Standard feature.

Answer (score -1):

head.h

```c
#pragma once

int f(int, int), g(int, int), h(int, int);
```

head.c

```c
#include "head.h"

int f(int x, int y) { return 0; }
int g(int x, int y) { return 0; }
int h(int x, int y) { return 0; }
```

main.c

```c
#include <iostream>
#include "head.h"

int main()
{
    f(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is technically a one-liner, but it has more repetition than the two-line solution in the question.

Comment: Why `iostream` in a `*.c` file, maybe you mean `stdio.h`?

Comment: The OP has exactly that (the declaration in your header) in the question already.  Evidently, they are looking for something different.